# What's Thom's Isotopy extension Theorem?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In Cheeger's paper "Finiteness theorems for Riemannian manifolds", in the proof of Lemma 4.1, he states that using Thom's isotopy extension theorem to replace Edwards and Kirby's deformation result (Lemma 3.5) there. I can not find the statement and the proof of Thom's isotopy extension theorem, could anyone help on this? Thanks.

Comment: "Isotopy extension theorem" ususally means the statement that isotopies of a submanifold can be extended to isotopies of the containing manifold. You find this in Section 1 of Hirsch's book on differential topology. I haven't checked how it applies to Cheeger's result.

Comment: Cheever's result need the estimate $d_{C^1}(H, id)< \epsilon$, where $H$ is the extension of $\varphi$, under the assumption $d_{C^1}(\varphi, id)< \epsilon$. I know Hirsch's book, it seems not enough for this case.

Comment: Is think you want the [Thom-Mather stratification theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Thom-Mather_stratification) In particular, the first isotopy lemma seems like it could be the one referred to.

Comment: @PaulBryan, I checked Thom's isotopy lemma before, and did not find it will implies the above extension result.